# Perform cross-difference in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to perform a 'cross-difference' as follows:

cross_diff ( [a,b], [c,d] ) = [ [ a - c, a - d], [ b - c, b - d] ]

I have a routine to do this in python as follows:

```
def crossdiff(a,b):
    c = []
    for a1 in range(len(a)):
        for b1 in range(len(b)):
            c.append (a[a1]-b[b1])
    x = numpy.array(c)
    x.reshape(len(a),len(b))
    return x
```

The problem is that I have to create a python array and stuff the results into it, then convert back to a numpy array.  I would like to be able to take numpy vectors a and b and get a numpy array c which contains all the differences, as the performance of the code above is poor for large vector sizes.

Is there away to perform the above calculation as "pure" numpy operations?

EDIT FOR TESTING RESULTS:

I ran all four implementations listed in this thread through the Python profiler for comparison.  I had to run them on a workstation since the initial implementation uses ~4GB of RAM with 10k elements.

```
import numpy
import cProfile

def cross_diff(A, B):
    return A[:,None] - B[None,:]

def crossdiff2 (a,b):
    ap = numpy.tile (a, (numpy.shape(b)[0],1))
    bp = numpy.tile (b, (numpy.shape(a)[0],1))

    return ap - bp.transpose()

def crossdiff(a,b):
    c = []
    for a1 in range(len(a)):
        for b1 in range(len(b)):
            c.append (a[a1]-b[b1])
    x = numpy.array(c)
    x.reshape(len(a),len(b))
    return x

a = numpy.array(range(10000))
b = numpy.array(range(10000))

cProfile.run('crossdiff (a,b)')
cProfile.run('crossdiff2 (a,b)')
cProfile.run('cross_diff (a,b)')
cProfile.run('numpy.subtract.outer (a,b)')
```

Results:
  Original python is 74.147 seconds, my version is 1.656 seconds, 3rd implementation 0.296 and 4th 0.288.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([a,b])[:,None] - np.array([c,d,e])[None,:]
```

A bit of explanation: The `None` in the index expands the dimension as much as needed. So, actually the calculation will be:

```
a a a     c d e     a-c  a-d  a-e
       -         =  
b b b     c d e     b-c  b-d  b-e
```

Surprisingly useful, the `None` in indexing.

One more example:

```
import numpy as np

def cross_diff(A, B):
    return A[:,None] - B[None,:]

vec_a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
vec_b = np.array([3,2,1])

print cross_diff(vec_a, vec_b)
```

Comment: the None in index is it something particular to numpy array or that can be done with any array?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: It is a NumPy trick. Basic python arrays do not support multi-dimensional indexing or any element-wise calculations.

Comment: I see the concept of replicating a by shape(b) and b by shape(a), but when I try this it returns an array of 1-element values, instead of n-element values.

Comment: @Guy, did you try my example? Put some numbers instead of `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`, and `e`. If you have 1d-arrays `A` and `B`, try `A[:,None] - B[None,:]`. I added a further example to the end of my answer.

Comment: I did try it, and i got this: 
`code`
>>> np.array([1,2,3])[:,None] - np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])
`code`

Comment: @DrV, Not sure what went wrong with my first try, but your updated cross-diff code works and is more elegant than my solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @Guy: The problem with your code was that you had `[:,None]` in both, whereas one of them must be `[None,:]` to expand vertically. Other than that, "my" solution is the standard Numpy solution, and has the benefit of being quite quick. I tried with two vectors of 10000 elements giving 100 million differences in 334 ms with my computer.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the same result without the explicit dimension adding for broadcasting by using the `.outer` method of ufuncs. For example:

```
>>> np.subtract.outer([1, 2], [3, 4, 5])
array([[-2, -3, -4],
       [-1, -2, -3]])
```

It has the added benefit of accepting any iterable as input, you don't need to first convert them to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Based on technique outlined by @DrV, I came up with this:

```
def crossdiff2 (a,b):
    ap = numpy.tile (a, (numpy.shape(b)[0],1))
    bp = numpy.tile (b, (numpy.shape(a)[0],1))

    print ap.transpose()

    return ap - bp.transpose()
```

Which gives the same answer as above but keeps all data manipulation in numpy.

Comment: Nice try! But do not try to over-optimize. This is much slower (appr. x 8) compared to the trivial solution :)